# Spring webflux, ServerRequest get client/Browser IP address

Tags: spring-webflux

Someone please help me to get Client Ip address in spring webflux functional program.

I have RouterFunction, which accepts ServerRequest and gives SeverResponse. But i want HttpServerRequest to getRemoteAddress().

Thanks Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

This will be supported in Spring Framework 5.1, with [SPR-16681](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16681):

```
ServerRequest request;
Optional<InetSocketAddress> address = request.remoteAddress();
```